# Fillable form checklist in excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to make a fillable form checklist in excel and have a question. The form would consist of:

Main section 
Helper section1
Helper section2
Helper section3
Helper section4
Bottom section

My question is, is it possible to have some kind of drop-down in the main section that duplicate the helper sections and stack them? The above structure would be the default, but for instance in the drop-down there'd be 1-10, 1 being the default and 2+ would repeat the helper sections the selected number of times. If I picked 4 there would be 4 "help section1"'s on top of each other and then same with 2-4...Main and bottom would only be 1 always. Each section consists of about 10 rows and 6 columns. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no way to do this without VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Use VBA to copy the sections as needed. you can use the record macro function to find what code you need to replicate the copy-paste operations.